# Entity Framework bug, insert command generation

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, postgresql

I am working with PostgreSql DB using Entity Framework:
When I add new item into DB it generates strange code:

```
INSERT INTO (SELECT "person_contact"."person_id" AS "person_id",
             "person_contact"."contact_id" AS "contact_id" 
             FROM "public"."person_contact" AS "person_contact")
       ("person_id","contact_id") 
       VALUES (cast(141792 as int8),cast(289406040 as int8))
```

So it add

```
SELECT "person_contact"."person_id" AS "person_id",
"person_contact"."contact_id" AS "contact_id" 
FROM "public"."person_contact" AS "person_contact"
```

instead of table name "public"."person_contact"

How to resolve this Entity Framework bug ???

UPD: Same issue when I try to delete "person_contact" entry. In delete statement instead of table name - select query.

Comment: EF doesn't generate SQL. Your PostgreSQL provider does. Talk to whoever wrote that.

Comment: I am using NPgsql provider. I think that this issue more related to EF than provider, because it happens only for this table. For another tables it works.

Comment: I'll repeat: The EF does not generate SQL.

Comment: May be I dinn't correctly understand EF architecture, but following this picture from MSDN, EF build command tree. Based on which is formed SQL code usind ADO.NET Data provider. But it doesn't matter. I have a problem with generating SQL code by Npgsql provider and EF.

Comment: Can you put your code that generated this SQL? Without seeing that, it is hard to see why these erroneous queries are being generated....

Comment: There is nothing special in code: just "person1.Add(contact1);" where person1 represent object related to person table and contact1 represent object related to contact table. "person_contact" table is used for connect data in person and contact table.

Comment: ADO.NET doesn't generate SQL, it executes the SQL your app provides. ADO.NET data providers are used to connect to specific database versions but they still DON'T generate the statements.

Comment: I have same problem. My Table is parent table where is trigger. Is it possible that it is problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to try and fix this:

- Firstly, it could be that your model has become corrupt. You could try deleting the model and recreating it. Also see my answer to this question: [SQL Server foreign keys messing with entity framework model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160265/sql-server-foreign-keys-messing-with-entity-framework-model/5164349#5164349)
- Secondly, you say that it only happens with this table. Is there anything special about this table.
- Thirdly, you could try a different .net connector for ProgressSQL, see: http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/entityframework.html

These are listed in the order that I would try them.

Comment: 1) It did not help. Model is recreating every time when there are any changes in DB.

Comment: 2) I can't find anything special with this table.  3) Is Devart dotConnect for PostgreSQL free for use? I was not able to find link where I am able to download it. Unfortunately, I cann't log in to their site. It throw 404 error any time when I try to login after registration.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you forgot to create primary key on this table.

I've had the same problem and the solution in my case was very simple. The problem was that I had a column named "id", but I forgot to make it Primary Key. The moment I set it as Primary Key everything was OK.

It is very strange, because EF, normaly won't import table without primary key, but when you have column named "id" it assumes that it is a primary key.

The structure of my table was:

```
*DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "public"."fact_season_tickets";
CREATE TABLE "public"."fact_season_tickets" (
"id" int8 DEFAULT nextval('fact_season_tickets_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
"season_ticket_id" int8 NOT NULL,
"date_key" int4 NOT NULL,
"station_id" int4 NOT NULL,
"amount" numeric(18,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
"status" int4 NOT NULL
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE)*
```

The generated by NpgSql INSERT statement was:

```
*INSERT INTO (SELECT "fact_season_tickets"."id",
    "fact_season_tickets"."season_ticket_id",+
    "fact_season_tickets"."date_key", 
    "fact_season_tickets"."station_id", 
    "fact_season_tickets"."amount", 
    "fact_season_tickets"."status" 
FROM "public"."fact_season_tickets" AS "fact_season_tickets") 
("season_ticket_id","date_key","station_id","amount","status") 
VALUES (510::int8,20150630,2,18.00::numeric,1) 
RETURNING "id"*
```

The solution was just creating a primary key:

```
*ALTER TABLE "public"."fact_season_tickets" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("id");*
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12630032)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "This does not provide an answer to the question". In my case THIS WAS the answer of the question. The "strange code" refered by Anton is generated because of missing primary key. Adding primary key to the table resolves the problem. It worked for me, I hope it will work for others too.

Comment: Illustrate your post with config or code sample for a better Answer quality.

Comment: I am trying to add some code samples, but when I try to submit my edit an error occures